# TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types bool and uint256

Tags: solidity, arrays

I am receiving the error: 'TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types bool and uint256'

my code is:

```
if (orderedScreening[0]/4 == orderedScreening[1]/4 == orderedScreening[2]/4 == orderedScreening[3]/4 == orderedScreening[4]/4) {
              f = true;
              }
```

^orderedScreening is a dynamic uint array.

I have already tried:

```
if (uint(orderedScreening[0]/4) == uint(orderedScreening[1]/4) == uint(orderedScreening[2]/4) == uint(orderedScreening[3]/4) == uint(orderedScreening[4]/4)) {
                  f = true;
                  }
```

and:

```
a = orderedScreening[0];
b = orderedScreening[1];
c = orderedScreening[2];
d = orderedScreening[3];
e = orderedScreening[4];

    if (a/4 == b/4 == c/4 == d/4 == e/4) {
                      f = true;
                      }
```

I also tested:

```
if (orderedScreening[0] == orderedScreening[1] == orderedScreening[2] == orderedScreening[3] == orderedScreening[4]) {
              f = true;
              }
```

and received the same error. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is Solidity, not Python.

Change this:

```
if (a/4 == b/4 == c/4 == d/4 == e/4)
```

To this:

```
if (a/4 == b/4 && b/4 == c/4 && c/4 == d/4 && d/4 == e/4)
```

Of course, in order to reduce gas-cost, you might want to store those intermediate results (at least `b/4`, `c/4` and `d/4`) in temporary variables before using them.